# Binding click event to expansion icon in tree table

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9, angular10

I am working on angular app. I am using tree table from primeng. In this tree table I have a expansion icon. Code is as follows:

Stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablestyle-demo

I want to bind a (click) event on this expansion panel and pass data to component on click of expansion icon and to want to know if it is expanded or not. I tried giving following code in div and tried binding click event to it, but it is not working

```
  <div (click)="toggleClicked(data)">  <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler> </div>
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `(onNodeExpand)` method written on `<p-treeTable></p-treeTable>` tag. You can write a function and pass `$event` to that function and know when your tree is expanded

```
 <p-treeTable (onNodeExpand)="onNodeExpand($event)" ... > 
  ...
  <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
 </p-treeTable>
```

Comment: how can I give space between outer rows? if a row is expanded then that node with children should be without space

Comment: Don't have any idea about that one! I think you better read the documentation and check other questions asked related to your question. @Roma